# Tutorial creates tables manually instead of letting hibernate do it, why?

Tags: spring, hibernate, dao

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-session-factory.jsp) on Spring Hibernate Integration Using SessionFactory. Scrolling down to DbUtil.java, an initialize method is used to create tables.

So far I haven't needed such a method as hibernate creates tables automatically. So what's the purpose of this initialiser? Are there any advantages? It *seems* like unnecessary complexity.

DbUtil.java

```
public void initialize(){
    DataSource dataSource = getDataSource();
    try {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE PERSON (ID INTEGER, NAME VARCHAR(50), EMAIL VARCHAR(100))");
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it's probably to show how it is done in case the property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is not set to create.
Commonly you wouldn't allow hibernate to automatically create tables on production environment (although someone does).

Comment: You should emphasize your second sentence ! `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is great in early developpement, but I cannot imagine not reviewing **by hand** a table (and views and indexes) creation script.